# ASP.NET: Firing batch jobs

Tags: c#, asp.net

My application could have up to roughly 100 requests for a batch job within a few milliseconds but in actuality, these job requests are being masked as one job request.
To fix this issue so that only one job request is just not feasible at the moment.

A workaround that I have thought is to program my application to fulfill only 1 batch job every x milliseconds, in this case I was thinking of 200 milliseconds, and ignore any other batch job that may come in within those 200 milliseconds or when my batch job have completed. After those 200 milliseconds are up or when the batch job is completed, my application will wait and accept 1 job request from that time on and it will not process any requests that may have been ignored before. Once my application accepts another job requests, it will repeat the cycle above.

What's the best way of doing this using .Net 4.0? Are there any boiler plate code that I can simply follow as a guide?

**Update**
Sorry for being unclear. I have added more details about my scenario. Also I just realized that my proposed workaround above will not work. Sorry guys, lol. Here's some background information.

I have an application that builds an index using files in a specified directory. When a file is added, deleted or modified in this directory, my application listens for these events using a FileSystemWatcher and re-indexes these files. The problem is that around 100 files can be added, deleted or modified by an external process and they occur very quickly, ie: within a few milliseconds. My end goal is to re-index these files after the last file change have occurred by the external process. The best solution is to modify the external process to signal my application when it has finished modifying the files I'm listening to but that's not feasible at the moment. Thus, I have to create a workaround.

A workaround that may solve my problem is to wait for the first file change. When the first file change have occurred, wait 200 milliseconds for any other subsequent file changes. Why 200 milliseconds? Because I'm hoping and confident that the external process can perform its file changes within 200 milliseconds. Once my application have waited for 200 milliseconds, I would like it to start a task that will re-index the files and go through another cycle of listening to a file change.

What's the best way of doing this?

Again, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I don't see how delaying the requests for 200ms will resolve the symptoms. it sounds like the workflow needs to be re-designed, otherwise you will find yourself in the same situation later on. Why not resolve the problem instead of working around the symptom?

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit too high level to guess at.

My guess is your application is run as a service, you have your requests come into your application and arrive in a queue to be processed.  And every 200 ms, you wake the queue and pop and item off for processing.

I'm confused about the "masked as one job request".  Since you mentioned you will "ignore any other batch job", my guess is you haven't arranged your code to accept the incoming requests in a queue.

Regardless, you will generally always have one application process running (your service) and if you choose you could spawn a new thread for each item you process in the queue.  You can monitor how much cpu/memory utilization this required and adjust the firing time (200ms) accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I may not be accurately understanding the problem, but my recommendation is to use the singleton pattern to work around this issue.

With the singleton approach, you can implement a lock on an object (the access method could potentially be something along the lines of BatchProcessor::GetBatchResults) that would then lock all requests to the batch job results object.  Once the batch has finished, the lock will be released, and the underlying object, will have the results of the batch job available.

Please keep in mind that this is a "work around".  There may be a better solution that involves looking into and changing the underlying business logic that causes multiple requests to come in for a job that's processing on demand.

**Update:** 
Here is a link for information regarding Singleton (includes code examples): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that the poster has some sort of an application that sits and waits for incoming requests to perform a batch job. The problem that he is receiving multiple requests within a short period of time that should actually have come in as just a single request. And, unfortunately, he is not able to solve this problem.

So, his solution is to assume that all requests received within a 200 ms timespan are the same, and  to only process these once. My concern with this would be whether this assumption is correct or not? This entirely depends on the sending systems and the environment in which this is being used. The general idea to be able to do this would be to update a lastReceived date/time when a request is processed. Then when a new request comes in, compare the current date/time to the lastReceived date/time and only process it if the difference is greater than 200 ms.

Other possible solutions:

1. You said you could not modify the sending application so only one job request was sent, but could you add additional information to it, for instance a unique identifier?
2. Could you store the parameters from the last job request and compare it with the next job request and only process them if they are different?

**Based on your Update**

Here is an example how you could wait 200ms using a Timer:

```
    static Timer timer;
    static int waitTime = 200; //in ms

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FileSystemWatcher fsw = new FileSystemWatcher();
        fsw.Path = @"C:\temp\";
        fsw.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(fsw_Created);
        fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void fsw_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime currTime = DateTime.Now;

        if (timer == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Started @ " + currTime);

            timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = waitTime;
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
            timer.Start();

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ignored @ " + currTime);
        }
    }

    static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Start task here

        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed @ " + DateTime.Now);
        timer = null;
    }
```

Comment: I think you have the best understanding of my problem. I could do 1) and 2). I have full control of the batch job and modify its behaviour.

The first workaround that I've proposed will not work. I have a second workaround, which involves firing the batch job after waiting 200 milliseconds as oppose to firing the batch job at the start of waiting 200 milliseconds.

Comment: Did the example above answer your question?